# Радиокнопки на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять как создать радиокнопки на чистом JavaScript нашла только как сделать чтобы тип был радиокнопок, а как подписать и сделать их активными попеременно не могу

```
Input {type = InputType.radio}
```

Это все что получилось найти Подскажите как быть дальше
Смотрела код радиокнопки но все равно не получается

> Как можно сделать кнопки не в строчку , а в столбик?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что Вы хотите получить на выходе? Вам необходимо создавать через `js` 2 радиокнопки, верно? и Сделать их зависимыми друг от друга?

Comment: Да нужно создать через js , и сделать так что ты нажимаешь одну ( и она активна) нажимаешь затем другую ( первая перестаёт быть активной,а вторая наоборот активна)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходимо только переключение между двумя `checkbox`, то можно так:

```js
    window.onload = function () { // Ожидаем загрузки страницы
        var z = document.createElement('input'); // Создаём первый элемент
        z.type = 'radio'; // Проставляем ему тип
        var z1 = document.createElement('input'); // Создаём второй элемент
        z1.type = 'radio'; // Проставляем и ему тип

        document.body.appendChild(z); // Добавляем первый элемент в body (Можно в div или любой другой элемент)
        document.body.appendChild(z1); // Добавляем второй элемент в body

        let bz = '';
        z.onchange = function () { // Проверяем изменение в кнопке.
            if (z.checked){// Если выбрано
                z1.checked = false;// То другому checkbox убираем значение
            }
        };
        z1.onchange = function () { // Проверяем изменение в кнопке.
            if (z1.checked){ // Если выбрано
                z.checked = false; // То другому checkbox убираем значение
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input')
input.type = "radio" // checkbox, и другие
input.checked = true // false
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```